# How to get User data Via User Model from firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I tried very hard; but, I can't able to get **user data via user Model** in **Profile Fragment** in my app. Here is the code which I have written in my project.

***ProfileFragment.java***

```
reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
        assert user != null;
        username.setText(user.getUserName());
        useremail.setText(user.getUserEmail());
        userphone.setText(user.getUserPhone());
        userdesc.setText(user.getUserDesc());
        if(user.getImageURL().equals("default")){
            profile_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.round_logo);
        }else {
            Picasso.with(getContext())
                    .load(user.getImageURL())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.round_logo)
                    .into(profile_image);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

***User.java***

```
package com.psb.farmersmarket.Model;

public class User {
    private String UserName;
    private String UserPhone;
    private String UserDesc;
    private String UserEmail;
    private String UserID;
    private String imageURL;

    public User(String userName,String userPhone,String userDesc,String userEmail, String userID, String imageURL) {
        this.UserName = userName;
        this.UserPhone = userPhone;
        this.UserDesc = userDesc;
        this.UserEmail = userEmail;
        this.UserID = userID;
        this.imageURL = imageURL;
    }

    public User() {
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return UserName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        UserName = userName;
    }

    public String getUserPhone() {
        return UserPhone;
    }

    public void setUserPhone(String userPhone) {
        UserPhone = userPhone;
    }

    public String getUserDesc() {
        return UserDesc;
    }

    public void setUserDesc(String userDesc) {
        UserDesc = userDesc;
    }

    public String getUserEmail() {
        return UserEmail;
    }

    public void setUserEmail(String userEmail) {
        UserEmail = userEmail;
    }

    public String getUserID() {
        return UserID;
    }

    public void setUserID(String userID) {
        UserID = userID;
    }

    public String getImageURL() {
        return imageURL;
    }

    public void setImageURL(String imageURL) {
        this.imageURL = imageURL;
    }
}
```

See the upper code. I wrote all getter & setter methods in the user model. Even though the error says the user has no setter methods. The error is also given below.

***Error Message***

```
W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for search found on class com.psb.farmersmarket.Model.User
W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for Description found on class com.psb.farmersmarket.Model.User
    No setter/field for name found on class com.psb.farmersmarket.Model.User
    No setter/field for user id found on class com.psb.farmersmarket.Model.User
    No setter/field for email found on class com.psb.farmersmarket.Model.User
W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for Phone No found on class com.psb.farmersmarket.Model.User
    No setter/field for status found on class com.psb.farmersmarket.Model.User
W/Settings: Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.
```

***Database***

[image]

*Please help me. Thanks in Advance.*

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Comment: just a sec. I will add this also

Comment: Screen shot of the database is added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the error message, it seems like your JSON looks like this:

```
"userid": {
  "search": "value", 
  "name": "value",
  "user id": "value",
  "email": "value",
  "Phone No": "value",
  "status": "value",
  "airplane_mode": "value"
}
```

There are two problems between this JSON and your code:

1. Not every property from the JSON has a field/property in the `User` class, which Firebase warns about.
2. Some properties from the JSON seem to have a field/property in the `User` class, but the name doesn't match.

You can fix both of these by using annotations in the Java code:

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class User {
    private String UserName;
    private String UserPhone;
    private String UserDesc;
    private String UserEmail;
    private String UserID;
    private String imageURL;

    public User(String userName,String userPhone,String userDesc,String userEmail, String userID, String imageURL) {
        this.UserName = userName;
        this.UserPhone = userPhone;
        this.UserDesc = userDesc;
        this.UserEmail = userEmail;
        this.UserID = userID;
        this.imageURL = imageURL;
    }

    public User() {
    }

    @PropertyName("name")
    public String getUserName() {
        return UserName;
    }

    @PropertyName("name")
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        UserName = userName;
    }

    @PropertyName("Phone No")
    public String getUserPhone() {
        return UserPhone;
    }

    @PropertyName("Phone No")
    public void setUserPhone(String userPhone) {
        UserPhone = userPhone;
    }

    @Exclude
    public String getUserDesc() {
        return UserDesc;
    }

    @Exclude
    public void setUserDesc(String userDesc) {
        UserDesc = userDesc;
    }

    @PropertyName("email")
    public String getUserEmail() {
        return UserEmail;
    }

    @PropertyName("email")
    public void setUserEmail(String userEmail) {
        UserEmail = userEmail;
    }

    @PropertyName("user id")
    public String getUserID() {
        return UserID;
    }

    @PropertyName("user id")
    public void setUserID(String userID) {
        UserID = userID;
    }

    @Exclude
    public String getImageURL() {
        return imageURL;
    }

    @Exclude
    public void setImageURL(String imageURL) {
        this.imageURL = imageURL;
    }
}
```

You'll see we have three annotations in here:

1. `@IgnoreExtraProperties` on the `User` class tells Firebase to ignore properties it finds in the database that don't have a matching field in the `User` class.
2. `@PropertyName(...)` on the getters/setters tells Firebase what JSON property to read this value from/write it to.
3. `@Exclude()` on the getters/setters tells Firebase to note write this value from the `User` class to the database.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer. The Error is gone. I am trying for the last 5 days on it. Once again very very thanks for your valuable answer